# How do I deploy an AngularJs app through github from a subfolder?

Tags: angularjs, git, github

I have an AngularJs web app that I've created and would like to deploy through github on a gh-pages branch.

Due to the structure of the project's files and directories the index.html file is not located in the root folder.  The file is buried a couple of levels deep.

How can I have github launch the app from the folder where my index.html file is located without changing my file structure?

Here is a link to my github repository: https://github.com/JustCant/CharTracker/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the base href inside your index.html file to `<username.github.io/repository-name>` or you can use the command below while building the final app to do the same -

```
ng build --prod --base-href=<username.github.io/repository-name>
```

Comment: I have added <base href='justcant.github.io/CharTracker'> to my head element with no luck.  I also tried <base href='<justcant.github.io/CharTracker>'>.  When that didn't work I tried the command line.  The CL threw the error 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: @Jace, try adding a forward slash at the end of your URL.
Like --base-href=username.github.io/repository-name/

Comment: Seems like you have not installed Angular CLI or you have not set the path variable.

Comment: I added the forward slash at the end of the URL, but no luck still.  I'll download the Angular CLI and try that out.  Just to clear things up, should I omit the angle brackets <> or include them?

Comment: If you are using the command to set base href then omit the angle brackets, but if you are writing it directly into the index.html then of course you have to use angle brackets around the base tag not around the link of your repository.

Comment: So far none of these methods have worked.  I'll keep researching and report back with any success I might have.